# Is the spiral of silence an original game model?

Tags: paradox, game-theory

What are the differences between the [spiral of silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_silence?wprov=sfla1) and the [prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma?wprov=sfla1)? Can the spiral of silence be skipped, or should it jump only to score points, as in the prisoner's dilemma?

Comment: The spiral of silence did not come out of game theory originally, but there is a game theory model of it, see [Blanco](https://ideas.repec.org/p/pra/mprapa/45452.html). There is a commonality with the prisoner's dilemma, the optimal outcome for players is when their choices align. But there are significant differences. First, in the spiral there is no choice asymmetry, whereas in the prisoner's dilemma it is specifically not talking that is jointly optimal, and second, the dynamic of the spiral depends on players communicating whereas in the prisoner's dilemma they must act blindly.

Comment: The example you give looks more like a different version of the spiral of silence. In general, the spiral of silence works towards the economic damage of the third player. I'll take that into consideration, and I'll look for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The *prisoner's dilemma* is basically a thought game, while the *spiral of silence* is more of a psychological disposition towards the social aspect of life, thus it is not primarily based on logic.

Comment: I take this into account and assume that the model is not unmodelable. In the prisoner's dilemma, there is no profit motive, and if the prisoner's dilemma arises as a result of the misapplication of this game-dependent game model, there is no profit motive that can be objected to. Consider that this game is only focused on loss or bankruptcy. You need to exit or disrupt the game for you to have any objections. Therefore, although the areas of application are different, they are very similar in principle.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of the intent of your question. But the spiral of silence is a sociological term. It is quite distinct from the prisoner's dilemma, which is understood as part of game theory. The spiral of silence could cause an individual to conform to a majority or minority view, dependent on the circumstances. There are exceptional individuals who tend not to conform. For example, passionate believers, neuro-divergent individuals, and those who have strong contrary evidence.

Comment: You stated it correctly. The spiral of silence depicts a sociopolitical map as a sociological concept. This makes society a system within the scope of the concept. Here, the minorities is what you state as shown in real life. Expressing it as a game model points to the effect of the dominance of the spiral of silence.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a reply.

In the spiral of silence, the group(s) defined as the minority/other side make passive profits. In the prisoner's dilemma, players don't play to make a profit.

The prisoner's dilemma is too abstract from the profit-time association to be expressed as a stand-alone game. If the prisoner's dilemma is expressed as a penalty model, it is within the scope of another game model. In the same way, the ineffectiveness of minorities in the spiral of silence can be expressed as a penalty model.
As will be noted below, one or more groups are comedians in the spiral of silence.

From the link shared by [Conifold](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/9148/conifold), I examined [Blanco's spiral of silence game model](https://ideas.repec.org/p/pra/mprapa/45452.html). I've seen that the game model is only for the majority side to score points, and the minority side is only as effective in the game as the number of profiles. The model did not favor the influence of the minority side in the game and is based on a strategy of intimidation of the minority in general. This means that majorities are competing with each other. According to this model, at least one group is comedians in the spiral of silence.

If the majority speaks and agrees, they will earn *Z<sub>v</sub>* points. If they do not agree, they will lose as many points as *s(C)*. This emphasizes the desire of the majority to be sufficient without concern the minority, and with it the imperial motivation to assimilate the minority.

If the majority has a score of less than *0*, society is taking action towards the goal of losing. Since this shows that the majority does not agree with the abstract reason minority*, there will be no such thing as borrowing, it will be exposed to a communication disorder that will be dependent on the minority.

There is something missing from this game model. That is, the minority side is not included in the game. When the spiral of silence is interpreted as a model of play, Schrödinger's cat is highly related to the thought experiment. However, since it is the majority that is focused on earning points, an explanation of the effect of the minority side on the game, no matter how many positive points the majority earns, has been overlooked.

> I assume there are two different sides in the game:
>
> - *Q = {A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, ...}* and *X = {B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub>, ...}*
> - *X* are groups that represent the other side. *Q* is the main society.
> - Each group plays a decisive role in the score by doing one of two actions: speaking and not speaking.
> - In each session, the speaking group says one of two different things: a dead cat or a live cat (more qualities can be added or quantities can be used. I found it appropriate to use the scoring system for the two attributes because they are simpler.).
> - In a session, *Q* groups can speak to each other and *X* groups can speak publicly.
> - If one of the *Q* groups speaks in a session and the others do not, the speaker is given a score of *-s(X)(s(Q)-1)*. The *s(X)* score determines the coefficient of being the main community-minded versus other groups. It is not defined as *0* points because in this way it acts contrary to the actions of the main group by acting at the minority level while the other groups do not speak in the session.
> - If at least two of the *Q* groups speak in one session, it is determined whether the speaking groups are agreed. If the number of speakers in the *Q* groups is different from the number of those who do not speak, it is decisive on both sides. It agreed that groups are divided into four as *q<sub>T</sub>*, *q<sub>F</sub>*, *x<sub>T</sub>*, *x<sub>F</sub>*.
> - If the number of elements of any of the *q* groups is *1*, *-s(X)(s(Q)-1)* is scored. If this number is greater than *1*, then *-s(X)(s(Q)-s(q<sub>p</sub>))+(s(X)(s(q<sub>p</sub>)-1))* is written to this *q* group.
> - Non-speaking groups should be called *Q<sub>-</sub>* and speaking groups should be called *Q<sub>+</sub>*. If *Q<sub>-</sub>+s(X)≤Q<sub>+</sub>*, then *Q<sub>-</sub>* groups are given *-s(X)(s(Q<sub>+</sub>))* points.
> - If groups *X* speak and groups *Q* do not speak in a session, groups *X* are not awarded.
> - There are coordination points (*μ*). These scores show how close the groups are to each other, including other groups. The coordination score is used to determine if players are in a balance that can continue the game. The monotonous continuation of the game shows that information about the society has been obtained at a level that can reach a conclusion.
> - If group *X* speaks in a session and at least one of the *Q* groups speaks, group *X* is awarded *s(Q<sub>+</sub>)s(Q)* and *s(q<sub>p</sub>)-s(q<sub>r</sub>)* coordination points. *q<sub>p</sub>* groups are given a coordination score of *s(q<sub>p</sub>)+s(x<sub>p</sub>)*, and *q<sub>r</sub>* groups are given a coordination score of *-(s(q<sub>r</sub>)+s(x<sub>r</sub>))*.
> - If one of the *Q* groups falls below *0* points, it will be replaced by the *X* groups with a score above *0*, because it will act in a way that is focused on losing points. If the coordination score of one of the groups, *j>μ>k*, exceeds the threshold of *n* or *-m*, it is removed from the helix because it does not prove its dominance as an alternative.
> - Among these teams, there are four different ace groups: these are the ones with peak points and peak coordination points. The game can allowed to continue until the last other side or one group remains.

As can be seen, the game can be exited and the game is not suitable for being fixed. This is also the reason why the spiral of silence is served: it is thought to have an infinite loop. However, if it continues in this way, it will be clear evidence that **war crimes** have been committed against other societies and the existence of the comedian group(s) is certain. Because the spiral of silence has the incompleteness to be defined as an inclusive game model. Once the spiral of silence is out or over, the player cannot be continued the game.